# Element alignment: Remove margin with modifier class not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a wrapper with two boxes in it. The boxes are each to other. In the boxes there is a title (optional) and a content. I have two cases. **First case:** One of the boxes has a title the other hasn't. **Second case:** Both boxes have a title. If you take a look on the example for the second case (both titles), the boxes and titles are aligned on the bottom of the wrapper, and the titles are also aligned. There is also an example for the first case (one box without title). Because of the missing title, the alignment isn't correct yet. Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

So what I tried is, to figure out the missing space for the first case, which was 21px. After this I select in CSS the second box and add the missing space. For the second case with both title, I tried to add a modifier class on the box and remove the margin-top. So default there would be a space on the second box if no title (this title is optional) and if both titles are avalable, a class should remove it again. Thats the part of the code:

```
.box + .box {
  margin-top: 21px;
}

.box--with-title {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Now with my idea it doesn't work. The first case is solved, but my class is not removing the margin. So now the alignment for the second case is wrong. Any ideas how to solve that the class is removing the margin or is there a bether way to do this with pure CSS? Hope this is clear enough.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-betweet;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  ;
  margin-top: 36px;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
}

.box__content {
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.box+.box {
  margin-top: 21px;
}

.box--with-title {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <h3>I have a title!</h3>
    <div class="box__content"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <h3></h3>
    <div class="box__content"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <h3>I have a title!</h3>
    <div class="box__content"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="box box--with-title">
    <h3>I have also a title!</h3>
    <div class="box__content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `align-items:flex-end` on the container and no need to consider margin:

> flex-end
>
> The cross-end margin edge of the flex item is flushed with
>   the cross-end edge of the line. <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items)</sup>

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items:flex-end;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  ;
  margin-top: 36px;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
}

.box__content {
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <h3>I have a title!</h3>
    <div class="box__content"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <div class="box__content"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <h3>I have a title!</h3>
    <div class="box__content"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="box box--with-title">
    <h3>I have also a title!</h3>
    <div class="box__content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

By the way your intial code was almost good, you are simply facing a specificity issue which make the rule of `.box--with-title` not being considered. You may do something like this instead:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-betweet;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  ;
  margin-top: 36px;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
}

.box__content {
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.box+.box {
  margin-top: 21px;
}

.box.box--with-title {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <h3>I have a title!</h3>
    <div class="box__content"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <h3></h3>
    <div class="box__content"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <h3>I have a title!</h3>
    <div class="box__content"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="box box--with-title">
    <h3>I have also a title!</h3>
    <div class="box__content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, I'll mark it as correct. By the way: Can you explain me for my own knowledge, why the class is not overriding the margin? I can't get it... :)

Comment: @MrBuggy specifity issue ;) `.box+.box` is more specific so override the other one ... add !important to the other one and it will work fine :)

Comment: @MrBuggy i added more explanation and corrected your initial code ;)